# Specify Release for single project during a Debug build using cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cmake

First a bit of background:

I have an existing cmake project that uses the Visual Studio 12 generator. In Visual Studio it is possible to specify build configuration on a per project basis. EG. The Solution is set to build Debug, but one project is set to build Release. For the application that I am working on, there is a dependency that deals with very large files, and in a debug build, this dependency not only runs very slow, but also hits the memory limit on 32 bit systems (Please do no suggest fixing the memory usage as a solution because that is not feasible in the short term). This project only has one developer, so other team members do not actively debug it, the project however, is a dependency for many other parts of the application, so I would like just this project to build in release mode. I can manually specify this option through visual studio, but I would like it to be the default build functionality.

Real Question:

**How do I specify project level build configurations for cmake's Visual Studio Generator?**

Comment: @ruslo, thank you for the suggestion, but there is more to that sentence. I've edited my question for clarity on this subject.

Comment: Do those settings get stored in `*.vcxproj.user` file? If so - I use `CONFIGURE_FILE` to generate a custom `.vsxproj.user` file for each target, in order to preset some common debugger options (path, arguments, working dir). Perhaps you could do something similar?

Comment: @DanMašek, I diffed the the files after changing the the settings in VS and the only file to change was the .sln. Currently, I wrote a script that runs cmake then manually alters the sln file afterwards. `{[PROJECT ID GOES HERE]}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32` -> `{[PROJECT ID GOES HERE]}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32`
This is pretty easy to alter, but I would like a solution through cmake so a separate script does not need to be distributed. I'll look into the CONFIGURE_FILE and see if it can be applied to the sln. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't think it will work with `.sln` file, since CMake actually creates that, as opposed to the `.user` file. TBH, in the situation you describe, i'd probably pull that dependency into a separate project and use a pre-built version in the main project (in similar fashion you probably use third party libraries).

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no way to do this in cmake. You can however use set_target_properties with the compile flag "/MD" which is a good enough work around. Thanks @Joel

Answer (score -3):

You can tell cmake during configuration time the type of the build with [CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html), for example:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```

Comment: This will set Visual Studio's "Active Configuration", which is the configuration for the whole solution, not just one project.

Comment: Not necesary you can test the main configuration and apply individual for each child project, so you need to dive into cmake, try [set_target_properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_target_properties.html) which let you apply such configurations.

Comment: @Joel your comment about set_target_properties set me on the right track. I used it to specify a conflicting flag /MD which overrides the /MDd flag. It's not an answer to my question, but it is a sufficient work around, so thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, @TheBat. =)